# Where do I add firebase.initializeApp() in my angular 7 project?

Tags: angular, firebase, angular7

Im trying to deploy my angular app to firebase hosting and I get the following error in console:
Uncaught FirebaseError: "projectId" not provided in firebase.initializeApp.

I have this in my app.module.ts:

```
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    afs.firestore.settings({
     timestampsInSnapshots: true,
   });
   afs.firestore.enablePersistence();
   firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
 }
}
```

Where exactly should I add the initializeApp command in app.module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways. To initialize it at the very top, do it as follows

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error when adding it to imports: Type 'App' is not assignable to type 'any[] | Type<any> | ModuleWithProviders<{}>'.
  Type 'App' is missing the following properties from type 'Type<any>': apply, call, bind, prototype, and 4 more.

Comment: imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'app' }),
    firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase),

Answer (score 0):

By the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup), it should be right after the configs placed.

```
// Initialize Firebase
// TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
var config = {
  apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
  authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

But Angular use it from the `environment`, so you can put it right on the first start.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If you are using `angularfire2`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase, 'fcc-book-trading'),
        AngularFireDatabaseModule
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```